# For loop iterating backwards?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a credit card validation task and when I check given numbers who are 16-digit long everything seemed to work fine, but that was not the case when I entered 15-digit number. Then while debugging with console.logs I noticed that my 'i' values are not what I expect them to be and it seems that is the reason why it doesn't work properly, but I can't fix it. Here is my code, sorry for a lot of console.logs...

```
const validateCred = (array) => {
  let sum = 0;
  let newArray = array.slice()
  let popped = newArray.pop()
  console.log(array)
  console.log(newArray, popped)
  let reversedArray = newArray.reverse();
  console.log(reversedArray, popped)  
  for (let i = 0; i < reversedArray.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log('value', i, array[i])
      array[i] = array[i] * 2 > 9 ? array[i] * 2 - 9 : array[i] * 2;
      console.log('new', array[i])
    } else {
      array[i] = array[i]
      console.log('value', i, array[i])
    }
    sum += array[i]
    console.log(sum)
  }
    sum += popped
    console.log(sum)
    sum % 10 === 0 ? console.log(true) : console.log(false)
}

const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
validateCred(valid3)
```

So, after I reverse the array, I expected that 'i' of 0 would be 3 and 'i' of 1 to be 2, but as you can see from console.logs 'i' of 2 is 7 as if I didn't reverse the array. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Within the loop you are doing `array[i]`, you need to do `reversedArray[i]`

Comment: `.reverse()` is a destructive operation. both `newArray` and `reversedArray` are reversed now. so do what @Matt said

Comment: I declared so many variables that I totally forgot about that one, thanks Matt, I would never see it!

Comment: @ivanmilenkovic don't forget the fact you reversed `newArray` too!

Comment: FYI, you should use a credit card validator lib like https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-validator -- checking length of 16 will not suffice

Comment: Statements like `array[i] = array[i]` also seem suspicious, doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl, should I avoid that completely or do something else?

Comment: Not sure what you had in mind to be honest. But that statement is doing nothing really. Similar to `let foo =123; foo = foo; console.log(foo)// 123`

Comment: I see, thanks. I just wanted to add something for case i % 2 !== 0, but it will be calculated correctly even if I remove that else block, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `for (let i = 0; i < reversedArray.length; i++) {` but you are running on `array[i]`. You need to use `reversedArray[i]`.

Comment: though matt already answered this as a comment 7 minutes ago, yes this is the reason.